# Update JTable in runtime

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a `JTable` which represents a database table. In runtime when I click a button I want to update my table from database. It is working if the button is in that panel where the table is. When I try to create an object from other class it is not working.

How can I update a `JTable` from outside of the class in running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just pass a reference to the `TableModel` to the other class. When the other class changes the `TableModel`, the `JTable` will be automatically updated.